# Неверное обновление окон tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю Python (3.6) и tkinter для написания упрощенной копии игры Hearthstone. 
Принял следующую концепцию: карта - кнопка; атака, здоровье и манакост - лейблы, упаковывающиеся в карту-кнопку.

Проблема: если навести курсор мыши на 1 карту и убрать оттуда курсор, то упакованные в другие карты лейблы перестают отрисовываться.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

global Click_number
Click_number = 0

def button_clicked():
    global Click_number
    Click_number = Click_number + 1
    print ("Клик! " + str(Click_number))
    Manacost_bar.config(text="%s" % Click_number)
    Manacost_bar2.config(text="%s" % Click_number)
    root.update()


root=Tk()
root.title('Card Prototype')
root.geometry('1280x720+300+200') #('ширина x высота+X+Y')

# кнопка по умолчанию
Card = Button(command=button_clicked, text="Похищение жизни")
Card.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0)
# кнопка с указанием родительского виджета и несколькими аргументами
Manacost_bar = Label(Card, bg="blue", fg="white", text="4")
Manacost_bar.grid(row=0, column=0)

Name_bar = Label(Card, bg="gray", fg="white", text="Chillwind Yeti")
Name_bar.grid(row=1, column=1)

HP_bar = Label(Card, bg="red", fg="white", text="5")
HP_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)

Attack_bar = Label(Card, bg="yellow", fg="black", text="4")
Attack_bar.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Dummy_bar = Label(Card, bg='green')
Dummy_bar = Label(Card, bg='green')
Dummy_bar.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1,ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=10)

Card2 = Button(command=button_clicked, text="Яд Провокация")
Card2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=0)
# кнопка с указанием родительского виджета и несколькими аргументами
Manacost_bar2 = Label(Card2, bg="blue", fg="white", text="1")
Manacost_bar2.grid(row=0, column=0)

Name_bar2 = Label(Card2, bg="gray", fg="white", text="Northshire Cleric")
Name_bar2.grid(row=1, column=1)

HP_bar2 = Label(Card2, bg="red", fg="white", text="3")
HP_bar2.grid(row=3, column=2)

Attack_bar2 = Label(Card2, bg="yellow", fg="black", text="1")
Attack_bar2.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Dummy_bar = Label(Card, bg='green')
Dummy_bar2 = Label(Card2, bg='green')
Dummy_bar2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1,ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=10)


Card3 = Button(command=button_clicked, text="Яд Провокация")
Card3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=0)
# кнопка с указанием родительского виджета и несколькими аргументами
Manacost_bar3 = Label(Card3, bg="blue", fg="white", text="1")
Manacost_bar3.grid(row=0, column=0)

Name_bar3 = Label(Card3, bg="gray", fg="white", text="Northshire Cleric")
Name_bar3.grid(row=1, column=1)

HP_bar3 = Label(Card3, bg="red", fg="white", text="3")
HP_bar3.grid(row=3, column=2)

Attack_bar3 = Label(Card3, bg="yellow", fg="black", text="1")
Attack_bar3.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Dummy_bar = Label(Card, bg='green')
Dummy_bar3 = Label(Card3, bg='green')
Dummy_bar3.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1,ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=10)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Нельзя упаковывать Label в Button, другие виджеты может содержать только само окно или специальный для этого виджет Frame.

Comment: Вообще PyQt будет более перспективнее чем Tk и удобнее, поэтому в будущем лучше присмотреться к PyQt.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки.
То есть, полностью кликабельную кнопку с упакованными в нее лейблами сделать не представляется возможным? Только кнопка, лейблы поверх кнопки и это все добро упаковать во фрейм, а фреймы в рут?

Comment: Да, придется так и делать. Библиотека Tk очень старая и годится в основном для создания самого примитивного интерфейса пользователя. В ней очень многого нет, но с другой стороны ее можно и выучить достаточно быстро.